# Wordpress failure, script does only run in "customizer"

Tags: javascript, wordpress

As you can read in the title my simple js script won't run on my wordpress site. However, when entering the wordpress customizer, the script works fine.

I thought the problem could be jQuery. So I tried to load jQuery in the header.php

```
function insert_jquery(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', false, array(), false, false);
}
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts','insert_jquery',1);
```

This is how I implemented the code into the site in funtions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_script('imagefade', '/additional-content/imagefade.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
```

But it won't help.

Did anybody experience similar problems?

Comment: what is the path of js file? is there any console error ? also make sure you have not included above code with in is_admin() condition

Comment: Have you looked in the console for an error when you're testing the script on the site?

Comment: No, I Didnt look into the console.
I tried to implement the script with the plugin "script n styles". Again, it just works in customizer mode